# How to deploy a streamlit app in compute engine

Tags: python, deployment, google-compute-engine, streamlit

I want to deploy a  python streamlit app using compute engine as my company does not provide access to app engine yet. Is there a way to deploy the app using compute engine rather than app engine on google cloud. I have searched multiple forum but unable to find relevant answers.

Sorry for the more general question; I hope someone can help me get over this hurdle or maybe point me to a resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is containerized, I would suggest deploying it to Google Cloud Run instead of Compute Engine. Cloud Run is a serverless cloud service used to easily deploy pre-built applications. One of its main advantages is that it automates most of the resources management process. Therefore, all you have to do is to tell Cloud Run where your Docker image is, and then Cloud Run will deploy it on a serverless environment without needing to specify the optimal number of resources for example.